# D3.js relocate element when zooming

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have multiple group elements with text element inside them. When I'm zooming with the mouse wheel, then everything is fine, my text is still inside my paths (polygons).

But when I'm zooming in automatically, then my text doesn't relocate.

Here is my function with auto zoom, I'm trying to find a specific path by ID, fill it with yellow, center and zoom to it.

```
function findByID(ID) {
                svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                    .data(feat.features)
                    .filter(function (d) {
                        if (d.properties.myID == ID) {

                            centered = centered !== d && d;

                            var paths = svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                                .classed("active", function (d) {
                                    d === centered;
                                });

                            var t0 = projection.translate(),
                                s0 = projection.scale();

                            projection.fitSize([width, height], centered);

                            var interpolateTranslate = d3.interpolate(t0, projection.translate()),
                                interpolateScale = d3.interpolate(s0, projection.scale());

                            var interpolator = function (t) {
                                projection.scale(interpolateScale(t))
                                    .translate(interpolateTranslate(t));
                                paths.attr("d", path);
                            };

                            d3.transition()
                                .duration(5000)
                                .tween("projection", function () {

                                    return interpolator;
                                });
                            return true;
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("fill", "#e9f356");
            }
```

Here is a screenshot where I used my mouse wheel:
[image]

And here is a screenshot after my auto zoom is done. My lines are fade away also, why is it so?

[image]

Edit: This is how I add my text:

```
svgContainer.selectAll(null)
                .data(feat.features.filter(function (d) { return d.properties.myId > 0; }))
                .enter()
                .append("g").attr("id", "txt")
                .attr("transform", function (a) {
                    var centro = path.centroid(a);
                    return "translate(" + centro[0] + "," + centro[1] + ")";
                })
                .append("text")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", function (d) {
                    var bb = path.bounds(d)
                    return ((bb[1][0] - bb[0][0]) / 10) + "px";
                })
                .text("A/10/10/3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it but when I try to zoom out with the mouse wheel it zooms out completely instantly. How can I make it smooth?

```
function findByID(ID) {
                svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                    .data(feat.features)
                    .filter(function (d) {
                        if (d.properties.myID == ID) {

                            var bounds = path.bounds(d),
                                dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
                                dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
                                x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
                                y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
                                scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
                                translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];


                            d3.select("#mainGroup").transition()
                                .duration(5000)
                                .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");

                            return true;
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("fill", "#e9f356");
            }
```